# UnknownAttribute event for LxSerializer

Tags: liquid-xml

Does there exist in LxSerializer something along the lines of the XmlSerializer UnknownAttribute event?

Liquid did a much better job parsing the xsd into c# code than xsd.exe did, but I need to be able to handle attributes that are not defined in the XSD.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please see the Liquid XML Objects documentation regarding [Unexpected Elements and Attributes](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/Reference/XmlDataBinding/xml-objects-code-unexpected-elements.html)

If 'Handle unknown nodes' option is true, any unexpected elements and attributes will be processed and added to a generic list of XElements and XAttributes.

If 'Handle unknown nodes' option is false, any unexpected elements and attributes will cause the error handler to be invoked.